# Translating Alamofire call to URLSession

Tags: swift, httprequest, alamofire

I've got a old codebase that I'm trying to migrate out of. The network calls currently use Alamofire 4.0 and I'm trying to use `URLSession` instead. I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong, here's what I've been doing. I start off with the route and params that I want to post:

```
// route to user creation
let url = ...

let params = ["user": ["first_name": "John", "last_name": "Appleseed", "email": "john@apple.com", "password": "asdfgh"]]
```

Here's the old and new network calls:

```
// old network request
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: newUser, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
  // ...
}

// new code
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
request.httpBody = jsonData
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  guard let data = data, error == nil else { return print("error=\(error)") }

  if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
    print("status code should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
    print("response = \(response)")
  }

  let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
  print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}

task.resume()
```

For some reason, I'm getting a status code of 400 in my `URLSession` attempt. Alamofire works fine.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @EricAya Forgot to write it in the question. Updated. I have it written in my project code though.

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong. Except maybe, try declaring the type of params like this: `let params: [String: Any] = ` it may help.

Comment: Also try replacing `.prettyPrinted` with `[]`, some servers do not like having pretty JSON in the httpBody.

Comment: Replaced `.prettyPrinted` with `[]`, but no dice :(

Comment: And `[String: Any]` didn't work either? Then I don't know. I hope someone else will be able to help you. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks Eric. Yeah, declaring an explicit type didn't make it any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the request isn't recognized as a JSON call. Write the following assignment after you create your `URLRequest`:

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
```